# App starts only each second time proper from background

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

On a test device, a **Sony Xperia E, `Android 4.1.1`** our `crosswalk` / `cordova` app starts only each second time proper from background.

- First time getting the app from background, you only see the last rendered view of app. No Inputs will be accepted..
- The second call from the background everything works as expected.

Please Note:

- that affects only the **Sony Xperia E, `Android 4.1.1`**, on several other android devices, it works as expected.
- this is unlimited repeatable.
- the relevant `adb logcat` ouput is in both cases them same
- Reproducible with:

  - `cordova4` / `crosswalk-10.39.235.15`
  - `cordova5` / `crosswalk-14.43.343.24`

Any suggestions why?

Comment: What is your question, then? Do we have to guess it?  What do you mean by freeze? What error is produced? What snippet of code might be causing this problem?

Comment: @SoroushA I updated my question a bit.

Comment: The question is still unclear. What do you mean by freeze? What error is produced? What snippet of code might be causing this problem?